# Peoplecode, SQLEXEC not retrieving correct data

Tags: oracle, toad, peoplesoft

<-------PeopleCode------>

Hi,

I have a SQL query that i have tried executing using both SQLEXEC and SQL.fetch() but the problem is, when I am passing the values to parameters (:1,:2...) it does not return a row but when I hardcode the values in the where clause of the query itself, it retrieves the correct value.
Can anybody help?

My query looks similar to the following sample query :
Select * from PS_rec1 where emplid=:1 and plan_type=:2

it returns no data till i hardcode the values.

I have checked the values at the back end and some data is there to be fetched. Moreover, the same query retrieves data when ran in TOAD.

Comment: I am writing this SQLEXEC in an app engine

Comment: Expecting help without giving enough details on the problem code, please think about putting the exact statement in your question.  And since you already mentioned you have listed the contents of your bind variables, include that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required another update to the same record to get the values fetched in SQL exec. 
M not sure what was the problem but i guess it might be that the previous update did not write the changes to the db even after an explicit commit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried outputting your binds to a log file just before you use them in your SQL statement?

If the binds aren't working, but literals are, then perhaps your binds don't contain the values that you expect them to.

You could also try explicitly setting the binds to the values that you're expecting just before the SQL statement.  This will prove that the way you're passing in the binds is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks Peoplesoft tipster, I did so by checking the bind values in a Messagebox, they contain the correct values as intended

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to put your exact SQLExec statement in the question.

But, do you really have "Select * ..." in a SQLExec?  How many columns are in your table? Since you mention the where clause, is your statement

```
SQLExec("select * from PS_rec where emplid=:1 and plan_type=:2", &var1, &var2, &vartocontainthewholerow);
```

Which will work in a SQL tool (toad) but probably does not work in AE or any type of Peoplecode program.

Now if your table has three columns, should you not have something like this:

```
SQLExec("select emplid, plan_type, column3 from PS_rec where emplid = :1 and plan_type=:2", &emplidIn, &plan_typeIn, &emplidOut, &plan_typeOut, &column3Out);
```

Notice that with three columns in the table that emplid and plan_type are two of them, you need to list all the columns you want, not asterisks '*'.  Kind of silly to select the emplid and plan_type though.

Comment: Sorry but I could not put up anymore information regarding the SQL at use. Anyways the issue was resolved. It was due to inconsistent updates before the SQL in question was getting executed.